# Random Deadlock in MySQL Session Table - Yii

Tags: php, mysql, session, yii, deadlock

I am getting random deadlock errors in MySql session table in Yii version 1.1.13 upon user login.

It appears the deadlock happens after two separate calls to the DB from system.web.CDbHttpSession

system.web.CDbHttpSession is part of the Yii framework. I don't think it is a bug in their code, as I can't find anyone else having this problem. I've got ZERO response on this over the last few months in the Yii forums. I cannot repeat the error, it happens at random. Which makes me suspect a misconfig in php or mysql? Anyways I am pulling my hair out trying to fix this.

Is suspect the two conflicting locks originate here in system.web.CDbHttpSession: Purging expired sessions:

```
public function openSession($savePath,$sessionName)
......
                            $db->createCommand()->delete($this->sessionTableName,'expire<:expire',array(':expire'=>time()));
......
    }
```

and updating the user's session

```
public function regenerateID($deleteOldSession=false)
......
                     if($deleteOldSession)
                            $db->createCommand()->update($this->sessionTableName,array(
                                    'id'=>$newID
                            ),'id=:oldID',array(':oldID'=>$oldID));
.....
```

Example of session config:

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'system.web.CDbHttpSession',
    'timeout' => (86400 * 30), //set timeout to 30 days
     ...
```

DB type: InnoDB with REPEATABLE-READ.

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_session` (
  `id` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `expire` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MySql info:

```
        ------------------------
        LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
        ------------------------
        140203 14:49:52
        *** (1) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 10FB67A3, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
        mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
        LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 2 row lock(s), undo log
        entries 1
        MySQL thread id 7460001, OS thread handle 0x4a1d3940, query id
        230752337 localhost dbUserName Updating
        UPDATE `tbl_session` SET `id`='b04gso5930mssafq6c3m7hrfj4' WHERE
        id='tuql5l5iru9cfim5u9qt81ld40'
        *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
        RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 1124 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of
        table `dbTableName`.`tbl_session` trx id 10FB67A3 lock_mode X
        locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
        Record lock, heap no 40 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format;
        info bits 0
         0: len 30; hex
        6230347364736463676c7162746438376e63326270667666343220202020; asc
        b04sdsdcglqbtd87nc2bpfvf42    ; (total 32 bytes);
         1: len 6; hex 00000f79076c; asc    y l;;
         2: len 7; hex fe00000bad0110; asc        ;;
         3: len 4; hex d2fb14fa; asc     ;;
         4: len 30; hex
        323134343833306666383235623135613538313738666561383839643237; asc
        2144830ff825b15a58178fea889d27; (total 93 bytes);

        *** (2) TRANSACTION:
        TRANSACTION 10FB67A1, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
        mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
        1067 lock struct(s), heap size 113080, 69260 row lock(s)
        MySQL thread id 7460002, OS thread handle 0x49a35940, query id
        230752335 localhost dbUserName updating
        DELETE FROM `tbl_session` WHERE expire<'1391467792'
        *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
        RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 1124 n bits 152 index `PRIMARY` of
        table `dbTableName`.`tbl_session` trx id 10FB67A1 lock_mode X
        Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format;
        info bits 0
         0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

Comment: What's your table structure? Specifically, is `expire` an indexed field?

Comment: Dcoder, I've added the DB structure to the post. No, expire is not an indexed field. Is that the solution? Sounds like an easy fix for me.

Comment: Based on the output you've provided, yes, that's my guess. It seems that `DELETE FROM tbl_session WHERE expire<:expire` is locking a large amount of rows while it sifts through them trying to match that condition.

Comment: Thanks Dcoder. I will index 'expire' and see what happens. The deadlock seems to be happening about every 3-4 weeks. I will report back then with an answer.

Comment: If you'd like to add that as an answer, I'd love to vote it up for you. Thanks again!

Comment: I would rather see if it actually helps before doing that :)

Comment: Did you find out wether it works with the expire index?

Comment: @Youri Added an index for expire seems to have fixed the problem. Haven't had any deadlocks since.

Comment: The `expire` index alone did not resolve my deadlock issues. I am trying something else now: slowing down the over-zealous expired session DELETEs in `CDbHttpSession` by adding a `LIMIT 100` clause, so less of the table is locked. If that doesn't work, I might remove the DELETE altogether, and see if the default PHP session gc call works by itself.